# using an attribute of an arraylist in my jsp with struts-bean.tld

Tags: java, struts-1, taglib

I have an issue using an attribute of an arraylist in my jsp.
The arraylist in my ActionForm :

```
private ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
```

The class declaration of the Account object in the Arraylist :

```
public class Account implements Serializable, Cloneable {
    private String bic;

    public String getBic() {
        return bic;
    }

    public void setBic(final String newBic) {
        bic = newBic;
    }
}
```

The call in my jsp :

```
<bean:write name="BankAccountsActionForm"
                            property="accounts.get(0).bic" />
```

The console error :

> javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No getter method for property accounts.get(0).bic of bean BankAccountsActionForm

Do you have a solution or another way to do this?

I have a terrible alternative using a property accountbic1 directly in the form. But it induces lots of work behind to re affect all the temporary attributes to the real `ArrayList`.

Comment: by `accounts[1]` are you trying to access the second element if the arraylist.?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I've found this on the web, but I'm using struts 1.1, maybe it was a later version of struts sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a collection of items in Struts 1.x, then use the `<logic:iterate>` tag.

Add the `struts-logic.tld` taglig on top of your JSP as follows:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic"%>
```

Then, using `<logic:present>` and `<logic:iterate>` you can iterate your `ArrayList` as follows:

```
<logic:present name="accounts">
    <logic:iterate id="account" name="accounts">
        <bean:write name="account.bic" />
    </logic:iterate>
</logic:present>
```

If you want to iterate a collection and access a particular index, use the `indexId` on `<logic:iterate>` like so:

```
<logic:present name="accounts">
    <logic:iterate id="account" name="accounts" indexId="index">
        <logic:equal name="index" value="0">
            <bean:write name="account.bic" />
        </logic:equal>
    </logic:iterate>
</logic:present>
```

The same can be done using JSTL:

```
<logic:present name="accounts">
    <logic:iterate id="account" name="accounts" indexId="index">
        <c:if test="${index == 0}">
            <bean:write name="account.bic" />
        </c:if>
    </logic:iterate>
</logic:present>
```

Make sure that `Account` class has a getter/setter method for attribute `bic`.

Comment: My aim here was to try on one element before iterate on all the collection. But, as I didn't resolve this problem, indeed I ended using this directly.

Comment: See my updated post to see how to use indexing on collections using Struts 1.x

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like:

```
<bean:write name="BankAccountsActionForm" property="accounts.get(1).bic" />
```

As it is a ArrayList not Array.

Make sure you have getter setter for accounts in in action class  ** BankAccountsActionForm **

```
public List getAccounts ();
public void setAccounts(List acc);
```

Comment: New console Error : No getter method for property accounts.get(0).bic of bean BankAccountsActionForm

Answer (score 0):

Change your setter and getter method name as per POJO standard as shown below :

```
public String getBic() { 
return bic; 
}

public void setBic(final String newBic)
 { bic = newBic; }
```

It will work fine

remove final from setter method and try again and write it as follows

```
 public void setBic(String bic )
     { this.bic = bic ; }
```

Comment: I did it, and updated the question with the news getter setter, but I still have the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply the error of getter and setter method. recode your getter and setter according to POJO standard as shown below:

Remove final from setter method and change your setter and getter method name as per POJO standard as shown below :

```
   public String getBic() {
    return bic;
}

public void setBic(String bic) {
    this.bic = bic;
}
```